# Merge [cameras] and [digital-cameras]

Tags: support, status-completed

I noticed that we have both [cameras](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameras) and [digital-cameras](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-cameras) in our inventory of tags.  I don't believe they are both necessary... I propose synonymizing them.  The only kind of camera broadly used today *is* the digital camera, and in the world of IoT, if someone is speaking about a camera, it will *definitely* be a digital camera.

Comment: Especially in terms of IoT, it needs to connect to some network, which makes it rather digital.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied [cameras](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameras) into [digital-cameras](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-cameras). No tag synonym is warranted; text completion will help the user find the correct tag.

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> → <kbd>digital-cameras</kbd>

Comment: What about [cameras] (http://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameras) and [digital-cameras] (http://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-cameras)? Shouldn't these be synonymised as the OP requests?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Ah, yes. The tags specified in the retag-request are wrong (or were changed).

Comment: Looks like they were always wrong - there are no edits on the questions to pluralise the tags (although I could have sworn when I looked that they **did** exist)

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Yes, the issue was pluralization.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.  It's unfortunate that this action appears to already have been taken, as it was probably mistaken.

"digital-camera" tends to refer devices that are specifically alternative to film cameras, which generally means handheld and human operated.  These would only infrequently be on-topic in an IoT context, and having lots of occurrences of that tag in external searches is likely to attract questions about general point-and-shoot camera support that have nothing to do with IoT.

In contrast, the kinds of cameras that *are* on topic in an IoT setting - streaming, recording, recognizing - while *implicitly* digital are essentially never referred to with that adjective.  Adding it is quite unnatural.