# Should we have a tag for surveillance cameras?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I do see a [digital-cameras](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-cameras) tag that is used to tag questions related to surveillance cameras.

I am proposing a separate *surveillance-cameras* tag which can be used to tag questions related to surveillance-cameras that have features of security, alerts, face recognition and are targeted towards the theme of surveillance.

Comment: Related: [Merge cameras and digital-cameras](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/49).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I agree that this would be useful. Feel free to edit that tag in to any relevant questions (the first use of the tag will create it).

Since surveillance cameras typically have more functionality than a typical camera might, it makes sense to have a specific tag. Having product-related tags may also be worth considering in the near future.